# VBA macro with multiple tasks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an excel macro that does a number of things:
Checks for a row that has all values equal or greater than 9
If said row's has all values like that it will highlight first cell in A column in red and after checking all rows it will output number of rows it highlighted.
So far I'm stuck with a code that gives a compiler error - expected function or variable. Could anyone assist in figuring this one out?

```
Public Sub test()

    S = 0
    j = 1
    A = 0
    For j = 3 To 7 Step 1
        If Cells(i, j) >= 9 Then A = A + 1
        End If
    Next
    If A = 5 Then
        Cells(1, j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        S = S + 1
    End If
    MsgBox (S)

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Read up on declaring variables (and using Option Explicit); 2) Indent your code to make it more readable; 3) Tell us which line errors.

Comment: And also consider that a variable that you did not set to a value will have an inital value. As you did not set `i` it will be an empty atring and `Cells(i,j)` will throw an error.

Comment: If that's all you are trying to achieve than you don't need VBA for this. You could use **Conditional Formatting** to highlight your cell and then get a count by using `Formulas`. Even better approach would be just to use formulas to get the count unless you really want to highlight the rows

Comment: Your first `IF` statement doesn't need an `End If` on the  next line as it's using single line syntax, your second `IF` statement does as it's using multi-line syntax. [IF...THEN...ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement).   When I compile the code I get an `End If without block If` error (providing I'm not using `Option Explicit` in which case I get a `variable not defined` error).

Answer (score 0):

Below i try to provide as much details as i can to fully explain each step. Make the necessary changes and try the below:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    Dim StartRow As Long, StartColumn As Long, LastColumn As Long, Lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, CounterValues As Long, CounterRows As Long

    StartRow = 2 'From which row will start the loop
    StartColumn = 1 'From which column will start the loop
    CounterRows = 0 'Reset Counter

    'Refer to the worksheets you work on
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row of column A

        'Loop Each Row from StartRow(2) to Lastrow (6)
        For i = StartRow To Lastrow

            LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find the last column of row i

            'Loop Each Column from StartColumn(1) To LastColumn(4)
            CounterValues = 0
            For j = StartColumn To LastColumn

                If .Cells(i, j).Value >= 9 Then
                    CounterValues = CounterValues + 1
                End If

            Next j

            'If all values are equal or greater thant 9
            If CounterValues = LastColumn Then
                'Color first row cell
                .Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                'Count color rows
                CounterRows = CounterRows + 1
            End If

        Next i

        MsgBox CounterRows

    End With

End Sub
```